# Post being redirected to attachment post

Tags: permalinks, attachments

That's strange issue I have on this one website. Similar to [this problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76923/pages-redirected-to-attachment-post) and I am trying to get this fixed from last couple of weeks.

This website have latest WordPress installed and `/%postname%/` permalink structure.

Sometimes, when I try to view a post, I get redirected to attachment post `/?attachment_id=358` instead of the post itself. This happens on posts when post and the attachment have the same title.

Although I can make the post working again if I change the permalink of the post. But that's too late since this website publish and share posts automatically. And users get error when they do not get to the right post.

I already tried disabling all plugins for a while. None worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason for this is the `get_page_by_path()` check inside the `WP_Query`, because it's checking for both `page` and `attachment` slugs, in this case.

So if we have both an attachment and a post with the `someslug` postname and visit:

```
example.tdl/someslug
```

then `get_page_by_path()` will generate the following query:

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent, post_type
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_name IN ('someslug')
AND post_type IN ('page','attachment')
```

and we're therefore served the attachment's page instead of the post's page.

So this seems to be a *core feature* but not a *bug* generated by your plugins.

### Workaround

Because of the permalink settings, the post request is handled like a page request.

We therefore have the `pagename` query variable constructed instead of the `name` query variable.

We can adjust the query variables, generated for the post request:

```
/**
 * Handle post requests correctly, in the case of the /%postname%/ permalink settings
 */
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'request', function( $query_vars )  
{
    if( 
           isset( $query_vars['pagename'] ) 
        && $post = get_page_by_path( $query_vars['pagename'], OBJECT, 'post' )
    ) {
        if( is_a( $post, '\WP_Post' ) )
        {
            // Add the 'name' query variable 
            $query_vars['name'] = $post->post_name;     

            // Unset the 'pagename' query variable
            unset( $query_vars['pagename'] );
        }
    }
    return $query_vars;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Here we check if a post exists with the `pagename` slug and if it exists, we construct the `name` query variable and finally unset the `pagename` query variable.

Now the post should be served instead of the attachment.

Comment: Is this `page` in last line `post_type IN ('page','attachment')`? shouldn't it be `post`? Because my problem is with posts. So any suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: Because of of your permalink settings, the `pagename` query variable is set, so your post *"walks" & "quacks" like a page,  and WordPress will then first try to find the ID of that page through `get_page_by_path()`, and it succeeds. Workarounds are possible, e.g. like I worked on  [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204439/26350) recently.  @Roberthue

Comment: I tried it and although it's not redirecting to attachment page but it's showing homepage now on this URL.

Comment: did you try the latest updated answer, with the return part that I first forgot ;-) @Roberthue

Comment: I tried the new code and it's working now. Conflicting posts are accessible now. BTW shouldn't this be included in WordPress by default? Because a lot of people use `/%postname%/` permalink settings.

Comment: great, yes it would be nice to have this core supported, because there are so many using this kind of permalink settings. Not sure if there's a ticket for this, haven't checked @Roberthue

Comment: Thanks a lot @birgire. I have been struggling with this issue from last few weeks without any success. I should have asked on WPSE earlier. :P

Comment: you're welcome, it's always fun to work on puzzles like this one ;-) @Roberthue